# Find the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n+\sqrt{n}} \frac{n^k}{k!}$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

This question has been asked so many times but for $k$ from $0$ to $n$, what would be different if $k$ goes to $n+\sqrt{n}$ instead. Any hints?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n+\sqrt{n}} \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

Answer (score 6):

Observe that your sum can be written in terms of the Poisson distribution as follows. Let $X_n$ be a Poisson random variable with mean $n$. Then
$$
e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n+\sqrt n}\frac{n^k}{k!}=\mathbb P(X_n\leq n+\sqrt n)=\mathbb P\left(\frac{X_n-\mathbb EX_n}{\sqrt{\mathbb EX_n^2}}\leq 1\right).
$$
Since $X_n$ can be written as a sum of $n$ independent and identically distributed random variables (each of which is Poisson with mean $1$) the central limit theorem applies, and therefore
$$
\frac{X_n-\mathbb EX_n}{\sqrt{\mathbb EX_n^2}}
$$
converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable as $n\to\infty$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282342/central-limit-theorem-poisson-equals-normal-tell-me-where-im-wrong) for an explanation.)
Thus your limit equals
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(\frac{X_n-\mathbb EX_n}{\sqrt{\mathbb EX_n^2}}\leq 1\right)=\mathbb P(Z\leq 1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^1e^{-x^2/2}\ dx,
$$
where $Z$ is standard normal.